# Jquery slide out menu - problems with code

Tags: jquery, menu

I've been playing around with a jquery slide out menu I found on on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fh6p4/

This is the code that does the sliding:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#button').toggle( 
    function() {
        $('#right').animate({ left: 150 }, '', function() {
            $('#button').html('Close');
        });
    }, 
    function() {
        $('#right').animate({ left: 0 }, '', function() {
            $('#button').html('Menu');
        });
    }
);
});//]]>  

</script>
```

This works perfectly with jquery 1.7.2 but on later versions eg 1.9.1 the button div #button disappears, I'm assuming the toggle function is not working correctly but cannot see where the problem is

Comment: Since the [.toggle(function, function, ... )](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) is removed in jquery 1.9+ onwards...

Comment: You can use the jQuery Migrate plugin like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fh6p4/709/) (_See we are using jQuery 1.9.1 and migrate pugin here_)

Comment: Thanx for that, I'm new to jquery and hadn't seen the migrate plugin

Answer (score 0):

[.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    $('#button').click(openMySlidingMenu);

    function openMySlidingMenu(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#button').click(closeMySlidingMenu);
        $('#right').stop().animate({ left: 250 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').html('Close');
            // is open
        });
    }

    function closeMySlidingMenu(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#button').click(openMySlidingMenu);
        $('#right').stop().animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').html('Menu');
           // is close
        });
    }
```

See it here:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fh6p4/711/)

Comment: There's a bug with this. Open and close the sliding menu a couple of times (at least 7 for me) and it'll significantly slow down.